# Hide columns in QgsAttributeTableView with Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I use this code to initialize QgsAttributeTableView and hide some columns in it in my custom widget:

```
def __init__(self, layer, canvas, hidden_columns, cache_size=5000, parent=None):
    """Constructor."""
    super(SomeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self._layer = layer
    self._canvas = canvas
    self._vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(self._layer, cache_size)
    self._attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(self._vector_layer_cache)
    self._attribute_table_model.loadLayer()
    self._attribute_table_filter_model = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(self._canvas, self._attribute_table_model)

    self._attribute_table_view.setModel(self._attribute_table_filter_model)
    self.setHidenColumns(hidden_columns)

def setHidenColumns(self, *args):
    self._config = self._layer.attributeTableConfig()
    columns = self._config.columns()
    for column in columns:
        if column.name in args:
            column.hidden = True
    self._config.setColumns(columns)
    self._attribute_table_view.setAttributeTableConfig(self._config)
```

But, no matter what, QgsAttributeTableView shows all the columns in the table. I try to apply self._config to self._layer, then add it to legend, open attribute table and everything works as expected (columns are hidden). That shows me that the config with hidden columns is correct. What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Possible dulicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318348/how-to-show-hidden-columns-in-qgis-3-6-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, setting table config on QgsAttributeTableView has no effect on column visibility. I have to set the column config on QgsAttributeTableFilterModel. This works for me:

```
def setHidenColumns(self, *args):
    self._config = self._layer.attributeTableConfig()
    columns = self._config.columns()
    for column in columns:
        if column.name in args:
            column.hidden = True
    self._config.setColumns(columns)
    self._attribute_table_filter_model.setAttributeTableConfig(self._config)
```

**EDIT**

After examining source code of QgsDualView, the propper way is to set config on QgsAttributeTableView as well as on QgsAttributeTableFilterModel and QgsVectorLayer itself. So this is final version of my code:

```
def setHidenColumns(self, *args):
    self._config = self._layer.attributeTableConfig()
    columns = self._config.columns()
    for column in columns:
        if column.name in args:
            column.hidden = True
    self._config.setColumns(columns)
    self._layer.setAttributeTableConfig(self._config)
    self._attribute_table_filter_model.setAttributeTableConfig(self._config)
    self._attribute_table_view.setAttributeTableConfig(self._config)
```